# How to find a specific tag/release on GitHub?

Tags: github

Is there a filter on GitHub interface to find specifics tags/releases by partial names? I would like to find out the date of known releases/tags... right now the only way I see how to do it is clicking the "next" and using CTRL+F to find the releases...

I would query for v1.0.* and it would output v1.0.0-rc.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2 and so on

Comment: `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/releases/tag/<tag>`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe pls check edit... I don't have the specific tag name... for example, my Kubernetes version is reported as 1.6.17, but his tag is a 404

Comment: Then not through the UI as far as I'm aware, but it'd be easy enough to do e.g. `curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/tags | jq 'map(.name)'` to get an array of all tag names

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can search for tags by typing in the search box in the dropdown menu where branches and tags are listed.

Screenshot for reference:
[image]